# Pandas import cvs: pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

my data in my file look like this

```
link    availability    product_type    
1   1016842-5       "GlamWhite Home Bleaching Refill Kit (6% Wasserstoffperoxid)"   
1   1045231-4       "Cabernet Sauvignon Burgenland Weingut Erich Scheiblhofer 2011 - 75cl"  
1   1045232-4       "Blaufränkisch Ried Oberer Wald Burgenland Ernst Triebaumer 2009 - 75cl"
```

And I am using pandas trying to read the csv with this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd


file_path = '/Users/nasiantalla/Downloads/pdsfeed (2).csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path,error_bad_lines=False,skiprows=1066576,sep='\t',lineterminator='\r', encoding='utf-8',header=0,
                    usecols=['availability', 'link'])
```

However I still get error:

```
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

I don't understand, I tried all the different encodings, but no luck.. Do you see something I haven't noticed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try without `skiprows=1066576,sep='\t',lineterminator='\r'`